# Cannot add Django management commands to project on my development environment

Tags: python, linux, django, python-2.7, virtualbox

I have an existing project with several custom management commands in an app. These commands run fine both locally and in production.

When I add a new command (newtask.py) to the folder however, it cannot be found.

When I run manage.py newtask, it says:

```
Unknown command: 'newtask'
```

If I open manage.py shell, and I try to import the file directly, like so:

```
from app.management.commands.newtask import Command
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named newtask
```

The app in question works fine, and *other commands in the same folder also work fine and can be imported*.

I handed this over to another developer I work with, and **he can run newtask on his local machine no problem**.

I have checked and double checked:

- Installed Apps
- I'm in the right virtualenv
- File permissions are the same as existing commands
- The file is not open in another application

I've also thought to copy existing, working code from another command into a new file. I get exactly the same issue - the new copy of a working command isn't found, cannot be imported, etc. Django just refuses to "see" it even though it's exactly the same and in the same folder.

So lets talk about environments.

My colleague (for whom the new command works) is working with Emacs on a native Linux environment.

I have a Windows 10 laptop, running Pycharm. My development requirement is a guest Ubuntu (16.04) install in VirtualBox. I edit the files in a shared folder using Pycharm and run the server in the Linux environment.

With this in mind, I have tried:

- Creating another new
  command in the Linux guest and put the code of a working command in
  there using vim. Same issue: command not found and cannot be
  imported.
- I've closed down Pycharm, closed all explorer windows and sat running
  nothing but Chrome in Windows in case there was file locking, but and
  still the file can't be located by Django.
- Restarted both operating systems.
- Changing branch on Git, and coming back to the branch again (getting desperate)

So to summarise the problem: **I cannot seem to get Django to recognise new management commands in my development environment (i.e. on a guest Ubuntu 16.04). Existing commands work and the same commands work on another environment.**

Any suggestions on things to eliminate and how to refine further would be gratefully received.

Comment: And if you rename the file to `newtask2.py` and run newtask2 as command?

Comment: @Melvyn: Renamed it and same issue.

Commands run:
`mv newtask.py newtask2.py`

In the management shell:

`>>> from app.management.commands import newtask2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name newtask2`

`>>> from app.management.commands.newtask2 import Command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named newtask2`

Comment: So that rules out file cache for a mounted virtual directly. I assume your user has write privileges for the directory. Is a file "newtask.pyc" being created? Gotta say this is odd. Like some weird encoding issue. And I assume all `__init__.py` files are present in the parent directories?

Comment: Can you run "ls -lr" on your /app/management/commands/ directory and share the output?

Comment: @Melvyn Yes, init is present, the other commands wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @IainShelvington: x1, x2 etc all work:

`-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  941 Sep 22 11:00 newtask2.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  938 Sep 22 11:39 newnewtask.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  226 Aug 23 14:46 __init__.pyc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 Jul 31 17:38 __init__.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  941 Jul 31 17:38 dummytask.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 3605 Sep 20 16:44 x4.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 2693 Sep 22 10:58 x3.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 3148 Sep 20 16:44 x2.py
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4716 Aug 23 14:46 x1.pyc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4857 Sep 20 16:44 x1.py`

Comment: And yet, no newtask.pyc?

Comment: @Melvyn: Nope. There's only the two pyc files actually. __init__ and x1.pyc (Command names censored). The existing commands all work by the way. Just ran one fine. No pyc file was generated though.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally cracked this. I had moved the repository earlier in the week, and due to some... custom virtualenv settings, it was loading the old repo when manage.py was run. This of course meant that it couldn't see the new files as they simply weren't where it was looking.

A simple problem manifesting in a non-simple way. Especially when I was running the manage.py in the correct repo.